# Ways to sync outlook calendar?

Tags: 7, datetime

I need to display the outlook calendar in the same calendar format in a page. I need to add events to the calendar and synchronize it with Outlook.

What module should I prefer to both synchronize with Outlook and display as calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Add to Cal](https://www.drupal.org/project/addtocal) module. I hope this module solve your query.

> A field formatter providing a widget for exporting events to:
>
> - Google Calendar
> - Yahoo! Calendar
> - iCal
> - Outlook
>
> The field formatter provides a button next to the field that shows a drop-down menu. This
>   menu contains links to the supported formats, and includes basic
>   styling that can be easily modified through CSS.

Comment: It just provides a field formatter not a calendar type display.

Comment: So you need a field of type calendar ?

Comment: not a field. I just want a calendar type of view with creating new events in it that reflects in outlook too.